# iOS7 - how can I build and archive my code base after losing all my secure key info

Tags: ios6, ios7, keychain

I recently had a computer crash, and all those secure key files I create/downloaded got wiped out since I had to reinstall everything on my new computer.

Now when I try to archive my code base, I get an error saying that "no provisioning files were found with a signing identity." Here is the screen shot of the error:

[image: screen shot]

Then I click "fix it" but it always comes back to this error. I think it is because my keychain access got wiped out. Would anyone know the steps to reset my keychain access with the correct settings?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to revoke all certificates in apple developer center and issue them again. Each certificate has a private key which is stored **only** in your (issuer) keychain, since you lost your keychain there is **no way** to return those private keys (other than if you had a backup)

Go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section of Member Center. On the left hand menu bar click on "Certificates". Make a list of certificates (hopefully you have one or two). Revoke them one by one. And create them again. You will need to create a certificate request  file (.certSigningRequest) from your keychain.

Here is a good article about creating certificates:

http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/generating-your-development-certificate/

Please make sure that you also downloaded the intermediate apple certificate which is available inside member center|certificate section. You will notice the link when you creating new certs.

If someone else was publishing/testing apps using your account you need to share the private key with them.

Here is another article from same site explaining how to export certs with private keys:

http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/how-to-share-an-apple-certificate-and-its-private-key/

PS. I used google to find out above article and both happened to be from same website!

Comment: hmmm. I am having trouble. I just created new keychain access certificates. Then I created a new provisioning file in the developer portal. Then I set the build settings in xCode to point to the new provisioning profile. But I still get that same error: no provisioning files were found with a signing identity.

Comment: Did you create Distribution Certificate as well?

Comment: your answer helped. I was able to solve the issue. Thank you very much :)